# DIV dropping down occasionally?

Tags: css, html

Hey, I am working on [my new site](http://flowdev.co.uk/). There is not much there yet but I have noticed in Chrome that on the first view of the page, so before refreshing, the social networking div drops down as if it has `clear: both` applied to it.

As soon as you refresh it is fine. It only seems to happen in Chrome too?

Can anyone think of a reason why? Any suggestions or ideas will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Here it is before refreshing.
[image]

And here it is after refreshing looking how it should. It only happens in Chrome for me.
[image]

Comment: I can't replicate the div dropping down when viewing that page, it looks the same in FF, IE and Chrome for me, can you post a screenshot of the problem?

Comment: Okay, added screenshots, a alt text box poped up on the second one but still.

Comment: Yeah it's as I said. When I check the website in Chrome it always looks like the second image, even before refreshing. Can't replicate so I can't really help...Sorry.

Comment: Thats okay, it kind of points towards my browser in particular then. I am using Chrome 9. Is this the same as yours? Also I am on a Mac. I am trying to narrow it down a bit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in the title you don't set float, the "social" div (float:right) has to be placed **before** the title ;)

check [this fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/steweb/YVJqJ/) out, and try to swap `<a>` with `<div>`

Comment: You got it in one. Although this is not as nice from an SEO stand point (I now have H2 above a H1, which I will have to change) it seems to be the only thing that works. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I am agree with @anothershrubery. And it shows proper in my browser.

However, it seems like that the problem is with floating the DIVs.

Dose this fiddle help you ? : [Formatting DIVs](http://jsfiddle.net/saranghdave/6ECBm/)

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Thank you.

**Suggestion** : Edit you system & browser configuration in your question. This will catch eye to responder.

Comment: Not particularly. I know how to align div's side by side. If it is showing up fine in other Chrome browsers then I am leaning towards the fact that Mac Chrome may be getting it wrong. I am just trying to find out what is causing it to drop. I will try wrapping my a tag in a div.